# “unknown type name 'decltype'”: Installing pyicu on mac failed, with gcc error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь запустить

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib sudo python3 -m pip install pyicu
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Installing collected packages: pyicu
  Running setup.py install for pyicu ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/mac/anaconda3/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-f_pe1bfd/pyicu/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hcsvnebo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Building PyICU 2.0.3 for ICU 58.2

    Adding CXXFLAGS="-I/Users/mac/anaconda3/include" from /Users/mac/anaconda3/bin/icu-config
    Adding LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata" from /Users/mac/anaconda3/bin/icu-config
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    copying PyICU.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/icu
    copying icu/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/icu
    running build_ext
    building '_icu' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/mac/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/mac/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/mac/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c _icu.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/_icu.o -DPYICU_VER="2.0.3" -I/Users/mac/anaconda3/include
    In file included from _icu.cpp:27:
    ./common.h:38:13: error: unknown type name 'decltype'
        typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
                ^
    ./common.h:38:30: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
        typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
                                 ^
                                 ;
    2 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/mac/anaconda3/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-f_pe1bfd/pyicu/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hcsvnebo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-f_pe1bfd/pyicu/
```

Comment: А `setuptools` стоит?

Comment: Да, стоит. Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages